# AMAZON: Add to remote cart without leaving site

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

Hey I'm trying to set up a remote cart. Very frustrating though since Amazon doesn't list any code examples for a remote cart without the customer leaving the site.

Here's where I'm at so far. I can get someone to leave my site and add the product from my site to Amazon using this (From: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/AddToCartForm.html):

```
<form method="GET" action="http://www.amazon.com/gp/aws/cart/add.html"> 
<input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="Access Key ID" />     <br/> 
<input type="hidden" name="AssociateTag" value="Associate Tag" /><br/> 
<p>One Product<br/> 
ASIN:<input type="text" name="ASIN.1"/><br/> 
Quantity:<input type="text" name="Quantity.1"/><br/> 
<p>Another Product<br/> 
ASIN:<input type="text" name="ASIN.2"/><br/> 
Quantity:<input type="text" name="Quantity.2"/><br/> 
</p> 
<input type="submit" name="add" value="add" /> 
</form>
```

But I want to make it so they can add an item to cart and stay on my site. It seems like this is how I accomplish that:

```
http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?
Service=AWSECommerceService&
AWSAccessKeyId=[AWS Access Key ID]&
AssociateTag=[Associate Tag]&
Operation=CartCreate&
Item.1.OfferListingId=B000062TU1&
Item.1.Quantity=2
&Timestamp=[YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ]
&Signature=[Request Signature]
```

But when I'm totally confused as to how to generate a timestamp and signature. Do I put this into a form action? Is there anywhere with code examples? I've been searching all day and can't find it. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this method to generate api request url, and its totally working fine. Believe this will help you

```
 $uri   = "/onca/xml";
 $asin  = "B00C5AHTC0";
 $end_point = "webservices.amazon.com";

          $params = array(
            "Service" => "AWSECommerceService",
            "Operation" => "CartCreate",
            'Version' => "2013-08-01",
            "AWSAccessKeyId" => AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
            "AssociateTag" => AWS_ASSOCIATE_TAG,
            "Item.1.ASIN" => $asin,
            "Item.1.Quantity" => "5",
            "Timestamp"=> gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z')
          );

        // Sort the parameters by key
        ksort($params);

        $pairs = array();

        foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
            array_push($pairs, rawurlencode($key) . "=" . rawurlencode($value));
        }

        // Generate the canonical query
        $canonical_query_string = join("&", $pairs);
        $string_to_sign         = "GET\n" . $end_point. "\n" . $uri . "\n" . $canonical_query_string;
        $signature              = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha256", $string_to_sign, AWS_SECRET_KEY, true));

        $request_url            = 'http://' . $end_point. $uri . '?' .$canonical_query_string . '&Signature='.rawurlencode($signature);
```